# How to prove $C=(A\setminus C)\setminus (B\setminus C)\setminus(A\setminus B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ sets. I'm trying to prove:
$$
C=(A\setminus C)\setminus (B\setminus C)\setminus(A\setminus B)
$$
I got stuck. Is it possible to show to prove it?

Comment: it does not even work with non empty $A=B=C$

Answer (score 1):

You can not prove that since the right side is a subset of $A\setminus C$ which is a subset of $A$.

Comment: Furthermore $A\setminus C$ does not include elements of $C$, so a subset of it *can not be* $C$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: Unless $C=\emptyset$.